# How to create an Intent that gives you suggestion every time you click

Tags: java, android, android-studio, share

I am developing an app, where I am using a Share Button whenever the user clicks on the share button the suggestion window will be opened like Messenger, WhatsApp, Bluetooth, etc.

But when I chose from suggestions, and the next time I click on share button it doesn't provide any suggestion but take me to the app which I chose last time from suggestion I cleared app Cache and App data also but doesn't work, direct me to the app that I chose from suggestion last time.

**Share Button Code:**

```
  Intent whatsappIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                whatsappIntent.setType("text/plain");
                whatsappIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, UserStatusforshare);
                whatsappIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
                whatsappIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET);

                try {
                    context.startActivity(whatsappIntent);
                } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {

                    Toast.makeText(context, "Whatsapp have not been installed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
```

**Alternate Code I have:**

```
Uri imgUri = Uri.parse(postImage);
            Intent whatsappIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            whatsappIntent.setType("text/plain");
            whatsappIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, postDescription);
            whatsappIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imgUri);
            whatsappIntent.setType("image/jpeg");
            whatsappIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
            whatsappIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET);

            try {
                context.startActivity(whatsappIntent);
            } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {

                Toast.makeText(context, "No supported app exists!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
```

Here in this code, there is one thing image here I am sharing an Image also... But that one work the same way doesn't provide suggestions every time click, direct me to the app I chose from the last only suggestions.

I've tried some answer from StackOverflow, but I am unable to understand and my search is also not very good... Please Help I am new to android, Thanks in Adnvance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try to start intent with this code :

```
       startActivity(Intent.createChooser(whatsappIntent, "The title what you want to show"));
```